# Calculate datetime correctly in UTC from date string

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the datetime in UTC, i have the bellow code and using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html)

```js
weeklyDish.orderBeforeTime = timeZoneToUTC(
  "Europe/Amsterdam",
  year,
  month,
  day,
  hours
);

function timeZoneToUTC(timezone, year, month, day, hours) {
  const dateObj = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:00`;
  const datetime = DateTime.fromFormat(dateObj, "yyyy-M-d H:mm", {
    zone: timezone,
  });
  return datetime.toUTC().toString();
}
```

The code above always return the wrong hour.

1. How can I get the year, month, hour and return a UTC string to save in the DB?
2. I'm going to be migrating data that has date as string (example: "2020-12-13"), how can I convert it to UTC date and subtract days correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to show an example to demonstrate your issue. The following shows use of Luxon's *UTC* and *setZone* methods that both seem to correctly convert a date set for "Europe/Amsterdam".

Note that the string passed to *DateTime.fromISO* must form a valid ISO 8601 timestamp like YYYY-MM-DDTHH.

```js
let DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

let [tz, y, m, d, h] = ["Europe/Amsterdam", '2020', '11', '30', '12'];

let date = DateTime.fromISO(`${y}-${m}-${d}T${h}`, { zone: "Europe/Amsterdam" });

console.log(tz + '\n' + date.toString());

let dateUTC = date.setZone('UTC');
console.log('setZone to UTC\n' + dateUTC.toString());

let dateUTC2 = date.toUTC();
console.log('toUTC method\n' + dateUTC2.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.25.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

PS Amsterdam standard time is +1, daylight saving time is +2.

Comment: Thanks @RobG, however when I send it a date like this ```let [tz, y, m, d, h] = ["Europe/Amsterdam", 2020, 2, 5, 4];``` i get ```Invalid DateTime```

Comment: Sorry, two digit values for month, day, etc. are required so that they form a valid ISO 8601 timestamp when concatenated so `let [tz, y, m, d, h] = ["Europe/Amsterdam", '2020','02', '05', '04']`

Answer (score 0):

If the date is already parsed, you can use the [date constructor directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Syntax). However, the constructor depends on the local timezone, luckily you can use [Date.UTC instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

The tricky part is about the timezone, which is not supported in the constructor, but it's a simple addition anyway.

So I'd wager something like so should work:

```js
function timeZoneToUTC(timezone, year, month, day, hours) {
  return new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hours + timezone));
}
```

**Note:** the month parameter is an index (0-based), so if you have 1=January, you need to decrease your month by one (as in my example).

**Edit:** uh, apparently, `Date.UTC` returns a timestamp, so you need to use the constructor anyway.

Comment: So-called timezones such as "Europe/Amsterdam" do not have fixed offsets, and often daylight saving must also be taken into consideration. Even where daylight saving is not observed, there will almost certainly be historical offset changes so it's not simply a matter of adding a fixed offset.

Comment: Good point! For a moment, I thought he was passing the offset, not the zone.